# How do I set the colormap for Image?

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm using the IPython Notebook on Chrome. I've been trying to display several images in a loop, so that they display one after the other. After no luck with imshow() or set_data() (weird JSON non_serialisable errors, even on uint8 data - same happens when I use Image() on a Numpy array) I wrote the following helper function:

```py
def fshow(im):
    imsave('/test.png',im)
    display(Image(filename='/test.png'))
```

which saves the image to a temporary file and then uses Image() to display it. It works beautifully - images pop up one after the other in the output cell, in real time, and I can intersperse them with Print statements if I want to.

But with monochrome images, they show up in the Jet colormap! So I used the following hack to save monochrome images as RGB images with identical colour channels...

```py
def fshow(im):
    sh=im.shape
    sh=(im.shape[0],im.shape[1],3)
    im2=zeros(sh)
    im2[:,:,0]=im
    im2[:,:,1]=im
    im2[:,:,2]=im
    imsave('/test.png',im2)
    display(Image(filename='/test.png'))
```

This is, however, a bit of a hack. So, how can I change the colormap which Image uses to display monochrome images?

And as we're here, how do I get Image() to display a Numpy array without complaining that it can't be JSON serialised?

Comment: Looks like it's imwrite's fault - when I open a grayscale image written by imwrite in an external viewer, it's in the jet colormap.

Comment: How do you create your images, and how to decide which are monochrome? `imsave` and `imshow` both provide an *cmap* keyword to specify which colormap to use (default is defined in rc image.cmap - very likely 'jet'), like `imsave(filename,data,cmap='gray').